# Better way to find the most common string in an array using only .get() and .size() methods

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to find the string with most duplicates in an alphabetically ordered array list. It's a custom ArrayList so I can only use the .get() and .size() methods for the array. Also if two or more strings are equally common, return the one that comes earliest.

This is what I have right now and it works, but I wanted to ask if there is a simpler method that doesn't use a second array list. Speed is also important factor here, so I'm aiming at O(n) complexity.

```
public String mostCommon(StringList a) {
    ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

        if (i == a.size() - 1) { //last line in the array is an empty line so we break the loop
            break;
        }

        int count = 1; //checks current string against the next ones
        int frequency = 0;

        while (a.get(i).equals(a.get(i + count))) {
            count++;
            frequency++;
        }

        if (frequency > max) {
            max = frequency;
            a2.add(a.get(i));
        }

    }
    return a2.get(a2.size() - 1);
}
```

Also, the last line in the array is an empty line.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a linear solution, and I can't readily think of anyway to do it faster than this, since you need to touch each string at least once (I'm prepared to be wrong).

Comment: *alphabetically ordered* is the key. So you have all occurrences of a string in sequence. Once you encounter a different string to the previous one, you won't encounter the previous one again. So just iterate and count.

Comment: also you don't necessarily have to check the whole list. if the number of occurrences of the current most common string is more than half the size of the array, you can stop

Comment: "if (i == a.size() - 1) {" does not add much value. you could get rid of it

Comment: I get an error without it, not sure why, I think it tries to compare it to to next index which doesn't exist.

Comment: then just do `for (int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {` ...

Comment: Oh yeah, in my defense It's my first year of university ;d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said the `List` is already sorted, so instead of the best counts of strings found so far (the `a2` List is redundant really), why not just count the longest sequence of the same string and remember that one until you find one that exceeds the best count so far:

```
public String mostCommon(StringList a) {
    String previous = null;
    int bestCount = 0;
    int count = 1;
    String bestString = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i).equals(previous)) { 
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }

        if (count > bestCount) {
            bestCount = count;
            bestString = a.get(i);
        }

        previous = a.get(i);
    }

    return bestString;
}
```

Comment: `if (a.get(i).equals(previous))` "previous" is initialized to `null`

Comment: So?  Calling `equals` with null will not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Ishnark suggested an optimization to this (see comments on question): if bestCount is bigger than the number of items left , you can stop early.